# GCP Function to call log based metrics from different projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to aggregate some logs from different GCP Projects so I can have a total count. I created log-based metrics in each of the projects that count the specific log instances, but now I have to agregate them into a single location so I can create an alert. I was thinking of creating a GCP function that calls the metrics from each project and then adds all the results into one.

I want to mention that I also need this count to be done over a large period of time, as the threshold could be triggered even after 6 months.

Is there a way of calling the log-based metrics using a GCP Function? Or is there a better way to aggregate the data from all the logs?

Comment: Have you tried using log sinks and log router? you can refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comment, cloud logging provides you with log sinks that can be used for aggregating the logs across the folders or your organization in GCP.  The following diagram illustrated how cloud logging routes and saves log entries(image is taken from official docs)

[image]

> Cloud Logging receives log entries with the Cloud Logging API where they pass through the Log Router. The sinks in the Log Router check each log entry against the existing inclusion filter and exclusion filters that determine which destinations, including Cloud Logging buckets, that the log entry should be sent to. You can use combinations of sinks to route logs to multiple destinations.
>
> The Log Router stores the logs temporarily. This behavior buffers against temporary disruptions and outages that might occur when a sink routes logs to a destination. The buffering doesn't protect against sink configuration errors. If your sink is configured incorrectly, then Logging discards the logs, an error log is generated, and an email notifying you of a sink configuration error is sent. (Source: [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Logging%20receives,error%20is%20sent.) )

**Configuring log sinks:**

The following are the steps involved in configuring a log sink for aggregating logs from various projects, as per this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2):

- Create a log sink: first you need to create a log sink, for creating a log sink using your console go to cloud logging and then select log router, click on create a log sink option and fill in the details. It will ask details on where you want to store your logs, select the backend of your choice. You can also use the following gcloud command for creating log sink

> ````
>    gcloud logging sinks create my-sink logging.googleapis.com/projects/myproject123/locations/global/buckets/my-bucket
> --log-filter='logName="projects/myproject123/logs/matched"' --description="My first sink"
>    ```
> ````

The above command is useful if you are creating a log sink with cloud storage as the backend.

- As you are trying to aggregate all the logs in a single place you need to follow the destination path formats for routing your log entries, follow the official documentation given above for more information.

After this all your logs will be aggregated at the same location you can now create a log based metric and create an alert or if you simply want to count the number of instances this metric has occurred, you can use **[Metric Query Language(MQL)](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples)** or you can also run sql queries on your logs using log analytics as mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/analyze/examples).

Answer (score 1):

On Kranthiveer Dontineni's recommendation I read on Log Sinks and created log sinks from each project to send the specific logs to a specific project. By doing that I now have all the logs in the same project and can create a log-based metric that counts all instances of the log.